# TypeError: Network request failed. React Native, Fetch API, iOS emulator

Tags: ios, react-native, rest, fetch-api

I cant reach my API on iOS emulator. The same code runs perfectly on the Android emulator. I tried a couple of other APIs just to test and everything works as intended (JSONPlaceholder with HTTPS and some random one that uses HTTP. Both GET and POST work fine).

### Code example of my fetch call:

```
  const login = async (authData) => {
  console.log('fetching...');
  //Setting up the request
  //Select apropriate port 8515 | 8516
  const port = handlePortSelection(authData.username);
  const url = `http:\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:${port}/api/Auth/LoginUser`;

  const headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'};

  const body = JSON.stringify(authData);

  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: body
  };

  try {
    //Call API
    const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);

    const data = await response.json();

    setUserData(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

#### My Info.plist file:

```
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

[iOS emulator error and Call Stack screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTvKd.png)

#### Here is my react-native info:

```
System:
OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5257U CPU @ 2.70GHz
Memory: 31.91 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 14.6.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.5 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.14.6 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.6.0/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.9.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
Android SDK:
API Levels: 28, 29, 30
Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 30.0.2
System Images: android-29 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
Android NDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 4.0 AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763
Xcode: 11.3.1/11C505 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 1.8.0_265 - /usr/bin/javac
Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
react-native: 0.63.2 => 0.63.2
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
react-native: Not Found
```

Any help wold be greatly appreciated! Tnx :)